# Read most recent excel file from folder PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, visual-studio

I have multiple .xlsx files placed in a folder. How can I read the latest file having today's date (modified date) in PYTHON? and further store the file name in a variable.

Comment: Does this not solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: Not really.
This is my code where I am hard coding the excel name manually:
import pyodbc as odbc
import pandas as pd
import yaml as yl
df = pd.read_excel(r'd:\Automate\2021927893014613.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
mdf = pd.concat(df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Save all .xlsx files paths and modification time into paths
paths = [(p.stat().st_mtime, p) for p in Path("path/to/folder").iterdir() if p.suffix == ".xlsx"]

# Sort them by the modification time
paths = sorted(paths, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

# Get the last modified file
last = paths[0][1]
```

Note that `last` is of type Path. If you want it as a string you can change the last line to

```py
last = str(paths[0][1])
```

Comment: Hey, how can I get the file name only that is being stored in variable 'last'?
Last variable contains complete file path, what if i only want to extract file name and store it in a variable?

Comment: then you need to change the last line to `last = paths[0][1].name`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os

# list all .xlsx files in absolute directory
files = (os.path.abspath(file) for file in os.listdir('/path/to/PYTHON') if file.endswith('.xlsx'))

# get their last updated time
files_and_updated_time = ((file, os.path.getmtime(file)) for file in files)

# sort out the lastest updated xlsx
last_updated_xlsx = sorted(files_and_updated_time, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# check if this said xlsx exists
# if so, store its absolute path in `result`
if last_updated_xlsx:
    result = last_updated_xlsx[0][0]
else:
    result = None
```

Comment: what is this parameter that you are trying to pass in os.listdir?
os.listdir('/path/to/PYTHON')

Comment: I mean, it is your "PYTHON" directory, but in absolute path. @MariamMehdi

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. Just put in your folder's absolute path :D

Comment: Getting this error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\mariam\\2021927893014613.xlsx'

Comment: Why is it reading file in C folder when I have mentioned my folder's path:
files = (os.path.abspath(file) for file in os.listdir('D:\Automate') if file.endswith('.xlsx'))
# get their last updated time
files_and_updated_time = ((file, os.path.getmtime(file)) for file in files)
# sort out the lastest updated xlsx
last_updated_xlsx = sorted(files_and_updated_time, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
if last_updated_xlsx:
    result = last_updated_xlsx[0][0]
else:
    result = None
df = pd.read_excel(result,sheet_name=None)

Comment: Could you show me what you get when running `[os.path.abspath(file) for file in os.listdir('/path/to/PYTHON') if file.endswith('.xlsx')]` ? I'm not sure if different os did something different.

Comment: The equivalent one liner should be `result = sorted([(os.path.abspath(file), os.path.getmtime(file)) for file in os.listdir('/path/to/directory') if file.endswith('.xlsx')], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0][0]`, without checking existence of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS are you on, but I have the solution for Linux/Raspberry Pi. Maybe only a little modification is needed for this solution to be implemented on Windows.

Importing libraries:

- To get today's date, use the `datetime` library.
- To find a file in a specified directory or folder, use the `os` library.

Now, for the coding part:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

# This gets today's date in string with the format of 2021-12-31.
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Assume your filename is only today's date and the extension at the end.
path = '/home/pi/' + today + '.xlsx'

# If there's a same filename found in this path.
if os.path.exists(path):
    print("File found")

    # Gets the filename from the path and store it in the 'filename' variable.
    filename = os.path.basename('/home/pi/' + path + '.xlsx')
    
else:
    print("File not found")
```