# (python) read specific type of .xlsx file name in a folder

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I search a few related discussions, such as
[Read most recent excel file from folder PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401661/read-most-recent-excel-file-from-folder-python;) however, it does not fit my requirement quite well.

Suppose I have a folder with the following .xlsx files

[image]

I want to read the files with name "**T2xxMhz**", i.e., the last 7 files.

I have the following codes

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = r'C:\Users\work'    # <--- find the folder
files = os.listdir(folder)   # <--- find files in the folder 'work'
dfs ={}
for i, file in enumerate(files):
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            dfs[i] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), sheet_name='Z=143', header = None, skiprows=[0], usecols = "B:M")   # <--- read specific sheet with the name 'Z=143'

num = i + 1   # <--- number of files.
```

However in this codes, I cannot differentiate two types of file name 'PYTEST' and 'T2XXX'.

How to deal with this problem? Any suggestions and hints please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use glob package. allows multiple usage of regexes

```
import glob
dir = 'path/to/files/'
flist = glob.glob(dir + 'T*Mhz*')
print(flist)
```

Comment: I just tried your method; however, it show '[ ]'. Should I use "T*Mhz"? or just "T" since the number after T is different?  Thanks!

Comment: There's a start after Mhz too.  

T\* - anything after T.
T\*Mhz - anything after T followed by Mhz, compulsorily.
T\*Mhz\* - anything after T followed by Mhz followed by anything - in this case extension of the file.